# Requiring users to click multiple buttons for one action

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design

So we are integrating a bulk editing feature for our users. Typically users want the ability to bulk edit numerous texts while being able to inline edit them.

Currently we have them click "replace" to activate the search and replace feature, but in order for it to make any actual changes, we require them to also click on "save" afterwards.

Have you experienced anything similar to this or what is your suggestion for providing a better UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you need users to confirm the changes to avoid any change taking place by accident. And in fact is not the same action, but a set of actions with at least 2 sub-actions: enable editing (fires action set **EDIT**), then the possible sub-action branches in the main action tree: ***save*** (sub-action 1) ***cancel/undo*** (sub-action 2)

Based on this, I'd recommend to have an *undo action* as well, since sometimes people may note remember what they have changed (see a simple mockup below)

[image]

Finally, if it's within your possibilities, try to have a **history** option so people can get back to a previous state

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly what I was hoping to hear.